# Localize iOS Automatically

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

I'm wondering if someone has a script out there that can take my Localizable.strings (english version) and using some free service like Google Translate automatically translate it any other language I specify. It would obviously have to be in the correct format. I could probably write this in a jiffy and post it on Github, but I'm wondering if something to this effect already exists?

Edit: Maybe I should clarify something for everyone who's been so pessimistic towards this. The only real text my app uses include single words like "close", "ok", "send", "left", "right". Google translate shouldn't have a problem with any of that irrespective of the language its translating to.

Comment: As a professional translator your question breaks my heart. :(

Comment: I'm sorry :( You know programmers .. always looking for the quickest way out

Comment: You realize if you used OneHourTranslation you would already have it translated? lol

Comment: You are mistaken if you think that Google tranlate won't have a problem with those words. For example, if you used "okay" in Japanese Google Translate will give you the word for "this is good (as apposed to bad)" and not the confirmation type of "okay". For the word "help" it gives you the verb to help lend someone a hand, not the menu option for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one a few months ago.

https://github.com/jkubicek/AutoLocalize

With recent changes to Google's translation services policy, its likely that it won't work anymore, but it shoudn't be too difficult to convert it to use Bing instead of google.

Comment: This is such a terrible idea.

Comment: And why is it such a terrible idea?

Comment: It's a terrible idea because, in theory, google will give you poor translations. I wouldn't be surprised if Google was at least as good as rock-bottom priced online translation services. In both cases, buyer beware, it's difficult/impossible to validate the quality of your translations.

Comment: Not in theory -- it absolutely will give you bad translations. Translation rely largely on context. Live translators are able to use the context to provide a translation. Without context your text will sound like it was generated by a computer. Seriously, unless all you are trying to translate is "Yes" and "No", it's not going to work well.

Comment: For those that are still interested in this, [SmoothLocalize.com](http://smoothlocalize.com)  will do it for 0.001 per word (to cover the cost of the Translate API). And you can choose human translations if you want for each language (4c per word).

Answer (score 3):

If there were such a script, you would be better off not localizing rather than localizing using something like google translate.

However, there are some good, inexpensive translation services out there. I personally use [OneHourTranslation](http://www.onehourtranslation.com/) and have been satisfied with the results. I've also heard of, but never used, [iCanLocalize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/services/software-localization/iphone-application-localization/), which has a streamlined localization process that allows you to upload the .strings file directly and download localized .strings files.

I had my last iPhone app localized in 5 languages for $65 USD, which is ridiculously cheap. Why wouldn't you just use a translation service?

Comment: Haha, so I was planning to get the translations reviewed as well. It should be alright then. I totally agree with you though :)

Comment: Don't be too sure. Google Translate fails completely compared to a translator when translating a simple word like 'Close' into my native language. That's because a word may translate into several other words but Google may not necessarily choose the correct one for the current context. For example the word close may mean close as in close something but it can also mean close as in close to something.